# Where does the Logistic Distribution get its name?

Tags: logistic, terminology, history, sigmoid-curve, logistic-distribution

Having read around on the topic I understand its application as a close approximation of the normal distribution with a nicer [mathematical form](https://www.statisticshowto.com/logistic-distribution/), but where does its name come from?

Is it associated with computer logic and its binary nature?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The cumulative distribution function of the [logistic distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_distribution) is the [logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)

$$
F(x) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-(x-\mu)/s}}
$$

For an explanation of where the logistic function got its name, check the [What does the name "Logistic Regression" mean?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111035/what-does-the-name-logistic-regression-mean) thread.

Comment: well shoot, I had always assumed that its name came from the inherent limits regarding the detailed coordination of a complex operation... e.g. "logistics"